# Displaying data from database from Controller to View using jQuery AJAX request CodeIgniter without refreshing the page

Tags: mysql, ajax, database, codeigniter

How i can load particular portion of page in Codeigniter? The Ajax is working but it reloads all views by calling controller name(like header, body, footer) but i want only reload body, How can i separate the code to work properly.

**Its Ajax code**

```
$('label#showdata').click(function(){

          var fromdate =document.getElementById('fromdate').value;
          var todate = $(this).val();
          var dataString = 'fromdate='+ fromdate+'todate='+todate;

            $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://chotigaadi.com/myadmin/references",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
        $("div#result").html(html).show();
        //alert(dataString);
        }
        });
      });
```

**Its my View**

```
<div class="col s12 m12">
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>myadmin/ExportCSV" method="POST">
        <div class="col s12 m3">
            <h5 class="center" style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">Registered Members List</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m2">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <label for="date"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Select from date below:</label>
                </br>
                <input name="fromdate" id="fromdate" type="date" class="datepicker" required>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m3">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <label for="date"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Select to date below:</label>
                </br>
                <input name="todate" id="todate" type="date" class="datepicker" required>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m4">
            <div class="col s6">
                <label id="showdata" class="btn waves-effect waves-light orange right" value="Show">Show Results</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
                <input type="submit" id="datesubmit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light green right" value="Export Data" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="result">
        <table class="highlight">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color:#ccc;">
                    <th data-field="name">ID</th>
                    <th data-field="name">Referee</th>
                    <th data-field="rname">Reference</th>
                    <th data-field="email">Email</th>
                    <th data-field="phone">Phone</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                      foreach ($results as $row)
                      {?>
                    <tr style="">

                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row->firstname;?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row->name; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row->email; ?>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row->phone; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php }?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Controller Code:**

```
function references(){
        if (!$this->check_user()) {
            redirect('myadmin/login/');
        }
        else
        {
            if(isset($_POST['fromdate']) && isset($_POST['todate']))
               { 
                $fromdate=new DateTime(str_replace("-","",$_POST['fromdate']));
                $fromdate=$fromdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $todate=new DateTime(str_replace("-","",$_POST['todate']));
                $todate=$todate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
               }
               else
                {
                $fromdate=new DateTime('2015-12-10 14:28:27');
                $fromdate=$fromdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
                $todate=new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
                $todate=$todate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                }


            $config = array();
            $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "myadmin/references";
            $config["total_rows"] = $this->myadmin_model->record_count($fromdate, $todate);
            $config["per_page"] = 8;
            $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
            $data["results"] = $this->myadmin_model->fetch_userdata($config["per_page"], $page, $fromdate, $todate);
            $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();



        $this->load->view('/admin/myadminheader');
        $this->load->view('/admin/myadmin',$data);
        $this->load->view('/admin/myadminfooter');
        }
    }
```

I want to reload only view as $this->load->view('/admin/myadmin',$data); by ajax How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change your middle part only than do not load header and footer in ajax calling function.

**Remove these two lines:**

```
$this->load->view('/admin/myadminheader'); 
$this->load->view('/admin/myadminfooter');
```

**It just only:**

```
$this->load->view('/admin/myadmin',$data);
```

This will only return the middle part not header footer in ajax response.

**Side note**:

If you are using this function directly from some where than you need to pass any param from ajax request for checking either request from ajax or not.

Comment: I tried this before but, the page displays content of body only without header menu & footer.

Comment: But what about reload of all script files & style sheets? Then what is use of ajax? @devpro

Comment: @suresh-shinde I suppose header and footer already loaded and CSS script files included in header.

Comment: How we can load header & footer before in controller? and which controller I want to call from Ajax. So it can work properly as page & without reload of header& footer.

Comment: @suresh-shinde u can call any function make sure header or footer not the part of div#result

Comment: I did same but, only body (that is div#result) part is displaying in page.

Comment: OK and when u add $this->load->view('/admin/myadminheader'); 
$this->load->view('/admin/myadminfooter'); what happened @suresh-shinde?

Answer (score 0):

Don't load the view in controller function. Just print the result in controller function and write a die() function after that. Clear the result div in JavaScript function before load the html.